# Return an array of a classes method names

Tags: vb.net

I've got the following. How do I query the class `myExample` and return an array of the class's method names?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x As New myExample

    '<<would like to return an array of x's method names i.e. {"hello","world","foo","bar"}

    Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit")
    Console.Read()
End Sub

Class myExample

    Public Shared y As Integer

    Public Sub hello()
        y = 1
    End Sub
    Public Sub world()
        y = 2
    End Sub
    Public Sub foo()
        y = 3
    End Sub
    Public Sub bar()
        y = 4
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods (incl. inherited):

```
Dim example As New myExample()
Dim t As Type = example.GetType()
Dim methods = t.GetMethods()
Dim allMethodNames() As String = methods.Select(Function(m) m.Name).ToArray()
```

[**`Type.GetMethods`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx)